# How to set progress dialog to not cancelable when being managed as a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a `ProgressDialog` managed as a `Fragment`. Even if I set the `ProgressDialog` to be non-cancelable, the BACK button will still operate to remove that `Fragment` from the stack. My inner class look like this:

```
public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private DialogStyle dialogStyle;

    public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        ProgressDialogFragment fragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("message", message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public void setDialogStyle(DialogStyle dialogStyle) {
        this.dialogStyle = dialogStyle;
    }


    @Override
    public ProgressDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String message = getArguments().getString("message");

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle(title);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(dialogStyle!=null) {
            switch (dialogStyle) {
                case CANCELABLE:
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    break;
                case NON_CANCELABLE:
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    break;

            }
        } else {
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        progressDialog.show();

        return progressDialog;
    }
}
```

And then the method I expose is:

```
public void showProgressDialog(String title, String message, DialogStyle dialogStyle) {
            Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress dialog");
            if(prev!=null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            DialogFragment newFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(title, message);
            ((ProgressDialogFragment)newFragment).setDialogStyle(dialogStyle);
            newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "progress dialog");
        }
```

So the obvious confusion here is that the BACK button removes the `ProgressDialog` because it's being managed as a `Fragment`. So how can I make it so that the `Dialog` is not cancelable?

Seems strange to try something like:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragmentManager.fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress dialog")!=null) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Android seems to be saying that ProgressDialog should not be used anymore, that instead you should “use a ProgressBar in your layout.” http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. They don’t say why, but I suppose it could be to avoid all the messiness in trying to handle unusual events after the wait (failed server calls, app returning from background task, etc.).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of ProgressDialog, why don't you try `setCancelable(false)` on  DialogFragment?

Comment: Good point! As simple as `public void setDialogStyle(DialogStyle dialogStyle) {
            this.setCancelable(dialogStyle==DialogStyle.CANCELABLE);
        }` (I'm using enum here)

Comment: `setCancelable` is also available on `ProgressDialog`. Don't understand what you mean by 'Instead of'

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `setCancelable(false)` on `ProgressDialog`