# android: progress DialogFragment does not get displayed at the beginning of the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-support-library

I´m using the compatibility library v4+.
Following other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338199/how-to-set-progress-dialog-to-not-cancelable-when-being-managed-as-a-fragment) and the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) I´m trying to create a fragment that calls a progress dialog from the activity that creates it.
The approach uses [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) displayed in the pre execute of an AsyncTask and dismissed (removed) on the post execute.
As result I don´t get the any dialog.... well, the truth is that the dialog gets displayed only for a fraction of second at the end of the thread.sleep.

Can someone tell me where I´m wrong?

I have my fragment here:

```
public class GroupsDetailsFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groups_details, container, false);

       return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        loadPage();
    }



    public void loadPage() {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadPage");
        new LoadPageTask(getBaseActivity()).execute();
    }

    public void executeLoadPagePreExecution() {Log.i(TAG, "executeLoadPagePreExecution"); }
    public void executeLoadPageInBackground() {Log.i(TAG, "executeLoadPageInBackground"); }
    public void executeLoadPagePostExecution() {try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }Log.i(TAG, "executeRefreshPostExecution"); }



    protected class LoadPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private Context context;

        public LoadPageTask(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // before the network request begins, show a progress indicator
            getBaseActivity().showLoadingProgressDialog(context);
            executeLoadPagePreExecution();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = executeLoadPage();
            Log.i(TAG, "error message result: " + result);
            return result;
        }


        // Returns null if Everything is OK. Error Message if any problem.
        private String executeLoadPage() {
            try {
                executeLoadPageInBackground();
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                return(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            executeLoadPagePostExecution();
            getBaseActivity().dismissProgressDialog();
            if (message!=null){
                Utility.showMessageAlertDialog(message, context);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And ProgressDialogFragment which is inner class of the FragmentActivity that dispays the fragment:

```
public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


        public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
            ProgressDialogFragment fragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("title", title);
            args.putString("message", message);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public ProgressDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String title = getArguments().getString("title");
            String message = getArguments().getString("message");

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle(title);
            progressDialog.setMessage(message);

            progressDialog.show();

            return progressDialog;
        }
    }


    public void showProgressDialog(String title, String message) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress dialog");
        if(prev!=null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        DialogFragment newFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(title, message);
        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "progress dialog");
        //fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void removeProgressDialog() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress dialog");
        if(prev!=null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: How about the setprogresstate method. Also how do you use the dialog fragment outside of the basefragment class? can you pass the getSupportFragmentManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should not pause the UI thread. So how about moving the Thread.Sleep() into doInBackground()?  Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, I know it. It was just a test... However, just out of curiosity after your answer I decided to give it a go. And funny enough (for my understanding at least..) it worked. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

doInBackGround is where the work is done on a worker thread (just not the UI thread), onPostExacute is what talks to the main UI.. that's why

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be calling

progressDialog.show() in onCreateDialog(...)